# Outlook appointments from sharepoint javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm working on trying to send a sharepoint outlook appointment from javascript. I have already been able to send emails and was wondering if there is anyway to send the appointments by attaching an .ics file along with it. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

- If you already have the calendar list and want to convert that item as an iCal refer this [link](http://virtualducttape.com/generating-an-ical-ics-file-from-a-sharepoint-calendar-list-item/).
- If you want to dynamically create iCal with custom parms you can create [.ics](https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js) file using this plugin. Upon creation save it in a library later attach it.

**Calendar item to ics file** - [link](http://virtualducttape.com/generating-an-ical-ics-file-from-a-sharepoint-calendar-list-item/).

```
http://<SITE_URL>/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={<LIST_GUID>}&CacheControl=1&ID=<ITEM_ID>&Using=event.ics
```

**Plugin to ics fle** - [link](https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js)

```
var cal = ics();
cal.addEvent(subject, description, location, begin, end);
cal.addEvent(subject, description, location, begin, end); // yes, you can have multiple events :-)
cal.download(filename);
```

> Note: Refer the original articles for better integration.